# SQL Select Distinct from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, distinct

I have the following statement which works just fine:

```
 select 'the file type is:', FileType 
 from table1
```

I would like to use `DISTINCT` with this statement, something like:

```
select 'the file type is:', distinct FileType 
from table1
```

but I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: distinct belongs at the front.  It works on the entire result set, and not a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` should come right after `SELECT`, like so:

`SELECT DISTINCT 'the file type is:', FileType FROM table1`

Answer (score 1):

The DISTINCT keyword applies to the entire result, not just one column. Try this:

```
select DISTINCT 'the file type is:', FileType from  table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put "DISTINCT" before any columns to be returned.